# Copying file into system32 of windows 7 using java

Tags: java

i am trying to copy files which are in jar file to the system32 folder of my machine using the following code

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd /c copy hello.dll c:\\windows\\system32\\");
```

But here the file is not copied???!!!!

but when iam giving

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd /c copy hello.dll c:\\windows\\");
```

the file is copied to the windows folder......
can any one help me..........

iam using a windows 7 machine

Comment: There must be access permission issue.

Comment: i have enabled my built in administration account.So i guess thats may not be the problem

Comment: When you ran the application, did you   Right Click -> Run As Administrator? Or if you are debugging in eclipse, command line, or your ide, did you run it as Administrator? It must be explicitly given to the app in all versions of Windows from 6.0 on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your command prompt(or IDE) is running in an Administrator mode, if your are running your program via command prompt.

Comment: ya its running in administrator console

Answer (score 1):

The app needs to be run as Administrator or you must prompt the user to raise their permissions to Administrator. In Windows 7, it is insufficient for the user to have Administrative privileges--as they could in xp. They must explicitly give the application permission to perform such a copy.

Comment: While this may be annoying to legitimate programmers, it's just another good level of safety against the less moral (or even novice) programmers.

Comment: @Zeychin, no kidding, I had one of my interns actually delete his entire root partition with a bug in his makefile the other day. Needless to say, he is no longer in the sudoers group.